# How can I use keybord keys like W, A, S and D in GLUT and C++?

Tags: c++, keyboard, glut

I want to use <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd> keys like `GLUT_KEY_LEFT`.

My Code:

```
if (key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT)
    rotate_y += 5;
else if (key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT)
    rotate_y -= 5;
else if (key == GLUT_KEY_UP)
    rotate_x += 5;
else if (key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN)
    rotate_x -= 5;

else if (key == GLUT_KEY_HOME)
    X1 += 0.5;
else if (key == GLUT_KEY_END)
    Y1 += 0.5;
else if (key == GLUT_KEY_INSERT)
    Z1 += 0.5;
```

Comment: So, what's your question here? And is it answered by anything more then pointing at intellisense/autocomplete/docs and GLUT_KEY_A?

Answer (score 3):

**[glutSpecialFunc](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node54.html)** is used to register a callback handler for special keys; as it's documentation notes:

> The special keyboard callback is triggered when keyboard function or directional keys are pressed.

For all other non-special keys you should register a second callback using **[glutKeyboardFunc](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node49.html)**, then just test for 'w', 'a', 's', 'd', etc in your code.

Again, from the documentation:

> glutKeyboardFunc sets the keyboard callback for the current window. When a user types into the window, each key press generating an ASCII character will generate a keyboard callback. The key callback parameter is the generated ASCII character. The state of modifier keys such as Shift cannot be determined directly; their only effect will be on the returned ASCII data. The x and y callback parameters indicate the mouse location in window relative coordinates when the key was pressed. When a new window is created, no keyboard callback is initially registered, and ASCII key strokes in the window are ignored. Passing NULL to glutKeyboardFunc disables the generation of keyboard callbacks.
>
> During a keyboard callback, glutGetModifiers may be called to determine the state of modifier keys when the keystroke generating the callback occurred.
>
> Also, see glutSpecialFunc for a means to detect non-ASCII key strokes.

So:

```
glutSpecialFunc (SpecialKeyHandler);
glutKeyboardFunc (NormalKeyHandler);
```

And:

```
void SpecialKeyHandler (int key, int x, int y)
{
    if (key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT)
        ; // do stuff
    if (key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT)
        ; // do other stuff
    // and so on...
}
```

And:

```
void NormalKeyHandler (unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    if (key == 'w')
        ; // do stuff
    else if (key == 'a')
        ; // do other stuff
    // and so on...
}
```